# Accumulation/limit points

Tags: sequences-and-series

The problem is:

> For the sequences
>
> 1. $(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{n}{2n+5}$,
> 2. $(-1)^{n+1}\dfrac{n}{2n^2+5}$ and
> 3. $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cos\Bigl(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\Bigr)$
>
> determine the accumulation points and limits (if they exist).

I am not quite sure how to start solving this problem. I think that I should use odd or even test, something like $2k$ for even and $2k+1$ for odd, but I get confused already at the beginning. Please help.

Comment: Substitute large numbers (for cases 1 and 2 odd and even) and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: sequences 2 and 3 converge, so there's only one limit point. Sequence 1 has two obviously convergent subsequences.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try proving 2 and 3 tend to 0, whereas number 1 has the even subsequence tending to $-\frac12$ and the odd subsequence tending to $\frac12$. So you have some limit points. Are there any others?